# threejs wireframe not working with OBJMTLLoader

Tags: three.js

am loading my object in threejs using OBJMTLLoader, the wireframe control is working alone for OBJLoader, but for the OBJMTLLoader it doesn't working

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( object ) {
                  object.children[0].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                  var  geometry = object.children[0].geometry;
                          console.log(geometry);
                  THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
                  geometry.dynamic = true;
                  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
                  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);  
                  scene.add( mesh );
                } );



function wireframe(){
                 //alert('hhhhhh');
                 mesh.material.wireframe = true;
              mesh.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0x6893DE  );
                }
```

but it causing the following error, so my model is not showing on the viewer,
so here i want to know that we can create wireframe on any kind of 3d models??

> object.children[0].geometry is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `OBJMTLLoader` returns a `THREE.Object3D` object which does have `.children`, you should not assume that the `.children` is of type `THREE.Mesh`. So you should actually `traverse()` the `THREE.Object3D` in order to find the `THREE.Mesh`.

```
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )

    // do something with the geometry

} );
```

Comment: Hi @gaitat now i don't have any error, but i applied the geometry and mesh but still the wireframe doesn't work, here look the code object.traverse( function ( child ) {if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
{child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
     var  geometry = child.geometry;
     
                   geometry.dynamic = true;
      
     }
     });

      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
                  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);  
                  scene.add( mesh );

Comment: You are defining the `geometry` inside the `traverse()` function and then you are using it outside the function. It is a matter of scope.

Comment: if i use geometry on inside traverse() am getting same result if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
     {
     child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
     var  geometry = child.geometry;
     console.log(geometry);
                   geometry.dynamic = true;
     
      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
                  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);  
                  
       
     }
     });

Comment: In this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dkbu2/ you can change the value of `useWireFrame` to see the effect. Initially I have a material set for the sphere and then with the `traverse()` I go and change that material to wireframe.

Comment: hey that is working fine,, thank you so much for the answer, and here we used MeshNormalMaterial can we use the default material used on the object with the wireframe ??

Comment: once again thank you.. How can we use default material ?? using the traverse can create the wireframe onClick?? just let me know i will try it and let you know

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with the problem. The question was about `object.children[0].geometry is undefined`. Is that solved ?